# How to replace substring in a string in c#

Tags: c#

I want to replace the substrings 134 and 1254 in a string

```
((startTime==134)&&(endTime==1254))
```

with some dynamic value - say, for example, 154 and 1234 respectively. 
I have written the code to place using `String.Split` method but it seems the code is very long. How can I make it shorter and more robust?

Here is the code:

```
string s = "((startTime==134)&&(endTime==1254))";
string[] time = s.Split(')').Reverse().ToArray();
var start = time.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("startTime")).Split('=')[2];
var end = time.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Contains("endTime")).Split('=')[2];
start ="154";
end = "1234"
time[3] = "((startTime=="+start;
time[2] = "&&(endTime=="+end;
string joinedstring;
joinedstring= String.Join(")", time.Reverse());
```

Comment: Fahim's answer is basically perfect solution to question as asked. You may want to clarify what your actual task is as `String.Format` (like `((startTime=={0})&&(endTime=={1}))`) or proper parsing of exception may be better approach to your actual problem (consider if new question is more appropriate if more complete requirements change it too much).

Answer (score 23):

Replace chars in a string using [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method as shown here

```
string output = input.Replace("old_value", "new_value");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest you can do without Regex.

```
    string str = "((startTime==134)&&(endTime==1254))";
    string[] timeArr = str.Replace("(","").Replace(")","").Split(new string[] { "&&" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] startArr = timeArr[0].Split(new string[] { "=="}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] endArr = timeArr[1].Split(new string[] { "=="}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    startArr[1] = "154";
    endArr[1] = "1234";
    string newStr = "(("+string.Join("==",startArr)+string.Join("==",endArr)+"))";
```